# How to connect Cloud SQL from different App Engine projects in Google Cloud?

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have two different projects in my Google Cloud account. I can connect my SQL server if App Engine exists in the same project. I'm trying to call SQL from my PHP project. I cannot connect App Engine to MySQL server.

Getting '**Unable to find the socket transport "unix" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?**'

```js
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    $host = ":/cloudsql/<myinstancename>";  
    $user = "myusername";
    $password = "mypassword";
    $dbname = "mydbname";
    mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);
    mysql_select_db($dbname);
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GAE PHP won't connect to Cloud SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21921855/gae-php-wont-connect-to-cloud-sql)